# How to compare the entered password with a sql database?

Tags: php, html, sql

This code should compare the entered password with a sql database:

```
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if($result == false)
    ?><script>alert('Wrong password')</script><?php
while ($result != false) {
    ?><script>alert('Right password')</script><?php
}
$connection->close();
```

But this doesent really check the entered password. But how to check the password?

Comment: @JosephSible Presumably this is what he meant, however this code is very dangerous for people who just come here and copy-paste.

Comment: You have an SQL syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Test whether `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]` are set, and if not, then don't do any of the checking that you do in PHP.